# Nifi not writing to GCP Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-nifi, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to send sample text messages to GCP Pub/Sub topic "ABC" using Nifi (PublishGCPubSub). However, I do not see any of those messages in cloud shell.

There is no issue in the topics as when I send sample message from cloud shell itself to the topic, I am able to read the same from the subscription in cloud shell.

Below is my nifi flow:

[image]

Comment: on the screenshot there is an error on PublishGCPubSub processor. please edit your question and provide error text. (better take it from the log file).

Comment: @daggett https://imgur.com/3acsDRl It is having problems with authentication. I am not sure what configurations to enter for the below:
1)Use Application Default Credentials
2)Use Compute Engine Credentials
3)Service Account JSON File
4)Service Account JSON
5)Proxy Configuration Service

Comment: please edit your question and put all information there.

Comment: I solved my problem. The issue was with the service account which was not setup for pub-sub. I used the correct service account json key and the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

This was resolved by the author:

> I solved my problem. The issue was with the service account which was not setup for pub-sub. I used the correct service account json key and the issue has been resolved.